# c++ displaying sentences in reverse order using pointers

Tags: c++

i'm trying to build a program that takes short sentences from the user and display them in reverse order. unfortunately, I just began c++ I need to know to do that.
for example: if user entered input:

```
I like the red color
blue is also nice
and green is lovely
but I don't like orange
```

output:

```
but I don't like orange
and green is lovely
blue is also nice
I like the red color
```

Thanks in advance!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE= 500;

int main()
{

   const int SIZE = 500;
   char mystring[SIZE];
int i;
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{

    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    cin.getline(mystring, SIZE);
    } while (mystring != 0);

       char * reverse= new char[strlen(mystring) + 1];
        char *p1 = mystring+ strlen(mystring);
        char *p2 = reverse;


        while(p1 != mystring)
        {
        p1--;
        *p2= *p1;
        p2++;
    }

    *p2 = '\0';
    cout << reverse<<endl;


   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: is std::string and reverse iterator an option for you?

Comment: When you read in a string from the user, copy it and push it onto a stack. Then pop off the stack until it's empty

Comment: @billz OP is trying to re-implement `tac`. string.reverse() won't serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A considerable way you're intended to approach this is the following algorithm:

1. Load the file into a buffer, terminating it with a null char.
2. Position a pointer `p` to the location of the last buffer slot.
3. While `p` is not pointing to the start of the buffer do the following:

   - If the character is a newline (`'\n'`) then

     1. Send the string *past* the newline (`p+1`) to stdout.
     2. Overwrite the newline pointed to by `p` with a null char.
   - Decrement `p` back one char position.
4. After the above loop is finished there is one line remaining: the first one. send it to stdout and you're done.

Or so I am led to believe. Important things to consider are the following:

1. Does the algorithm work with an empty file?
2. Does the algorithm work with a file containing ONLY newlines?
3. Does the algorithm work with a multi-line file WITH NO trailing newline?
4. Does the algorithm work with a single line file WITH NO trailing newline?
5. Does the algorithm work with a multi-line file WITH trailing newline?
6. Does the algorithm work with a single line file WITH trailing newline?

That being said, here is a potential candidate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // assume the file to reverse-print is the first
    //  command-line parameter. if we don't have one
    //  we need to leave now.
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // will hold our file data
    std::vector<char> data;

    // open file, turning off white-space skipping
    ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    inf.seekg(0, inf.end);
    size_t len = inf.tellg();
    inf.seekg(0, inf.beg);

    // resize buffer to hold (len+1) chars
    data.resize(len+1);
    inf.read(&data[0], len);
    data[len] = 0; // terminator

    // walk the buffer backwards. at each newline, send
    //  everything *past* it to stdout, then overwrite the
    //  newline char with a nullchar (0), and continue on.
    char *start = &data[0];
    char *p = start + (data.size()-1);
    for (;p != start; --p)
    {
        if (*p == '\n')
        {
            if (*(p+1))
                cout << (p+1) << endl;
            *p = 0;
        }
    }

    // last line (the first line)
    cout << p << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Input**

```
I like the red color
blue is also nice
and green is lovely
but I don't like orange
```

**Output**

```
but I don't like orange
and green is lovely
blue is also nice
I like the red color
```

---

**A Considerably Simpler Approach**

There are ***much*** simpler ways to do this, and I'll explain each step in comment along the way. Chance are you can't use something like this, but it is important you understand what is available to you when you *can*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // assume the file to reverse-print is the first
    //  command-line parameter. if we don't have one
    //  we need to leave now.
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // collection that will hold our lines of text
    vector<string> lines;

    // read lines one at a time until none are returned
    //  pushing each line in to our vector.
    ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    string line;
    while (getline(inf, line))
        lines.push_back(line);
    inf.close();

    // a LOT happens in the next single line of code, and
    //  I will try to describe each step along the way.
    //
    // we use std::copy() to copy all "items" from
    //   a beginning and ending iterator pair. the
    //   target of the copy is another iterator.
    //
    //  our target iterator for our formatted ouput
    //   is a special iterator class designed to
    //   perform an output-stream insertion operation
    //   (thats the << operator) to the stream it is
    //   constructed with (in our case cout) using each
    //   item we give it from our copy-iteration. to use
    //   this class the "copied" item must support the
    //   traditional insertion operator <<, which of
    //   course, std::string does. after each item is
    //   written, the provided suffix (in our case \n)
    //   is written as well. without this all the lines
    //   would be ganged together.
    //
    //  lastly, to glue this together (and the whole
    //   reason we're here), we use a pair of special
    //   iterators designed to  work just like the regular
    //   begin() and end() iterators you're familiar with,
    //   when traversing forward in a sequence, but these
    //   ones, rbegin() and rend(), move from the last
    //   item in the sequence to the first item, which is
    //   *exactly* what we need.

    copy(lines.rbegin(), lines.rend(), 
         ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    // and thats it.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Input**

```
I like the red color
blue is also nice
and green is lovely
but I don't like orange
```

**Output**

```
but I don't like orange
and green is lovely
blue is also nice
I like the red color
```

---

**UPDATE: Incorporating User Input**

An example of incorporating user input for the second version would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // collection that will hold our lines of text
    vector<string> lines;
    do
    {   // prompt the user
        cout << "Sentance (<enter> to exit): ";
        string line;
        if (!getline(cin, line) || line.empty())
            break;
        lines.push_back(line);
    } while (true);

    // send back to output using reverse iterators
    //  to switch line order.
    copy(lines.rbegin(), lines.rend(),
         ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for that, but how to do this if data not from file, i mean if data are given by user, is there a difference??

Comment: for example, if the user asked to "enter a sentence< 0 to quit or ctl-z what ever:,,?

Comment: @Todd Terribly sorry I was out and couldn't answer earlier. There are a number of ways you could do it. The second one would actually be easiest to accomplish, as you could change the input source to be `cin` rather than a local filestream, and turn it into a do-prompt-read-test-loop. The rest would ultimately be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it, but I'm having hard time figuring out how to change the source to be cin , which means to ask the user to enter those sentences?1 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
// include headers and avoid having to use std:: all the time
int main(){
    vector<string> data;
    string line;
    do{
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        data.push_back( line );
    }while( cin );//read lines and store to a vector
    for (int i=data.size()-1;i>=0;--i)// traverse the vector in a reversed order (maybe size_t for i would be better)
        cout<<data[i]<<endl;
}
```

Looks like it's some homework and probably you are restricted to use some features. 
If you insist, we can write a *homework-safe* version:

```
// this is just intended to illustrate how RIDICULOUS it is not to use STL features.
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
#define MAXLEN (10000)
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(MAXLEN);//allocate space from heap
    char* buffer_ptr = buffer + 1;
    *buffer = '\0';//string terminator
    while( fgets(buffer_ptr,buffer+MAXLEN-buffer_ptr , stdin ) ){
        buffer_ptr += strlen(buffer_ptr);
        ++buffer_ptr;// reserve the '\0'
    }
    buffer_ptr -= 2;
    while(buffer_ptr >= buffer){
        if (!*buffer_ptr)// find end of string
            fputs(buffer_ptr+1,stdout);
        --buffer_ptr;// traverse backward
    }
    free(buffer);//free space
}
```

which avoids C++ extension whenever possible. (In a possibly ridiculous way)

Comment: Thank you, actually I need to use pointers to that, it would be great if I can use vector.

Comment: @Todd, you need to tell us the exact words of your assignment. If you want to use pointers you could use char[] instead of string. It'd be kinda stupid, but it might serve your purpose.

Comment: yea, actually i'm using char, what im thinking about is how to point every first char from each line to display that, I dont know if thats right!!

Comment: @phoeagon, in the first version that uses a `vector<string>` it is indeed a bad thing to use an `int` to iterate over the `vector` (what if the container contains more than INT_MAX items?). Unfortunately you can't just change it to a `size_t` because the end-of-loop condition needs a signed integer. Much better is to use the container's reverse iterators `for (auto i = data.rbegin(); i != data.rend(); ++i) std::cout << *i << std::endl;` (and in general, you should always prefer iterators to indexing unless you really need random access).

Comment: @syam I understand that `vector<std::string>::iterator` is more desirable. But `auto` keyword doesn't work well enough on many older platforms and the type name is a bit too long and usually a bit overkill for small tasks like this.

Comment: @phoeagon, let's agree to disagree then. Correctness should always be #1 priority even over typing speed/ease, and even more when addressing a self-proclaimed beginner. Besides it's not *that* long to type `std::vector<std::string>::reverse_iterator`...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[100][100];
    for(int i =0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        cin.getline(str[i],100);
    }
    for(int i = 9 ; i >=0 ; i--) {
        cout<<str[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it pretty.

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b; It e;

  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};

template<class It>
range_t<It> range(It s, It f) {
  return {s,f};
}
```

`range( start, finish )` is a helper that lets you create a range that can be `for(:)` iterated over.

```
template<class C>
auto backwards(C&& c) {
  using std::rbegin; using std::rend;
  return range( rbegin(c), rend(c) );
}
```

`backwards(container)` returns a range that iterates over the container backwards.

Once we have written the above library code, all the heavy lifting is done.  The remaining code reads almost as pretty as [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Enter some text (blank line to finish):\n";
  std::string line;
  std::vector<std::string> lines;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    lines.push_back(line);
  for (auto&& line:backwards(lines))
    std::cout << line << "\n";
}
```

We get lines, buffer them, then print them backwards.

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Q0pPjG).

The goal here is to make the main program logic as clear as possible.  The `backwards` and `range` boilerplate just serves that need.